# How can I dynamically change a joint defined in the URDF of a robot during runtime to update the parent link?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, ros-noetic, gazebo-11

I'm currently working on a robotics project using ROS and Gazebo, and I'm facing the challenge of dynamically updating the parent link of a joint in the URDF during runtime. My goal is to modify the robot's structure in real-time within the simulation environment.

I've explored various options, including Gazebo plugins and ROS mechanisms, but I'm uncertain about the most effective approach. Has anyone successfully implemented a solution for updating the parent link of a joint during runtime? If so, could you please share insights, examples, or best practices?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or experiences related to dynamically modifying joint parent links in the URDF.